# How can I checkout a project from CVS?

Tags: cvs

I have never used cvs in my life (only git, svn) - can anyone tell me how in the world I can get the source/jar of this bundle to my local Ubuntu box?

http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.equinox/compendium/bundles/org.eclipse.equinox.http/?root=RT_Project

I've installed "cvs" into ubuntu, but "cvs co" command complains about some "CVSROOT" not being set.

EDIT: Thanks to duffymo I've set up my CVSROOT variable, now when I try to "cvs co" I get the following:

```
penguin:~/Downloads$ cvs co dev.eclipse.org:/cvsroot/rt
cvs checkout: cannot find module `dev.eclipse.org:/cvsroot/rt' - ignored
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out everything is much easier than I thought.
Simply bring up the "CVS Repositories" view in Eclipse, right click on it (yes - on the empty window!) and click "Paste connection" link, which looks something like this:

```
http://wiki.eclipse.org/CVS_Howto#Anonymous_CVS
```

Thanks to Eclipse doc:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/CVS_Howto#Anonymous_CVS

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this: maybe it'll help.

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1216619.html

Comment: Thanks, now I am getting "cannot find module" error... See my edit above :-)